# Unable to read parquet file with fastparquet but works with pyarrow - nullable ints

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow, fastparquet

Currently running some code like this:

```
df = pd.read_parquet('/tmp/my-file.parquet', engine='pyarrow')
```

I was having memory consumption issues since the files are large so I wanted to investigate is `fastparquet` would work better for memory usage.

When I switch the engine:

```
df = pd.read_parquet('/tmp/my-file.parquet', engine='fastparquet')
```

This line now throws an error like this:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

I believe this is happening because I have an integer field that contains nulls.  I can't find any documentation that says this is not supported.

Any ideas on why this is happening or how to workaround while still using fastparquet?

Comment: Can you show the full error traceback? (or even better would be a reproducible example)